# How to convert string written as array to actual array in php?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a simple way to convert this:
`$string = "[4164,8720,10303,10340,10627]"`
to an actual array? I know that i can use explode and implode, but when i receive huge string like above, i have some speed issues with my web site. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That data is valid JSON, so you can simply use `json_decode`.

Comment: try : $ar = json_decode($string, TRUE);

Comment: define "huge". Define "speed issues". What exactly is the size of the data which  causes problems, and what exactly happens? In this specific case you could use json_decode. explode won't entirely do the job here anyway because of the square brackets, you'd need to trim them first.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you people! the json_decode($string, TRUE); solved my problem!